# Powershell export to csv sum of timespan

Tags: powershell

I need to export to a csv file the result of a sum timespans values.

```
 $outItems = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List[System.Object]

 [TimeSpan[]]$outItems = foreach ($eachtimer in $DurationColl){

 if ($eachtimer -match 'H|M|S'){
   Convert-TimeString -Time  $eachtimer -Format 'm\Ms\.fff\S' }
 else {
   Convert-TimeString -Time $eachtimer -Format "h\:mm\:ss"} 
}

 $seconds = ($outItems | Measure-Object -Property TotalMilliseconds -Sum).Sum
 $ts =  [timespan]::FromMilliseconds($seconds) 
 $ert =  ("{0:hh\:mm\:ss\,fff}" -f $ts) 
 $ert | Export-Csv  C:\Users\User\Documents\output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

The $ert value is 04:05:38,631 and on csv appear the property lenght.
In resume, my Export-Csv doesn't work.

Thanks for any help

Comment: `Export-CSV` converts an input object’s properties into columns and their values into rows. When you provide only a string, the only property of a string is `Length`. You could do `[pscustomobject]@{Time = $ert} | export-csv ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Export-Csv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv?view=powershell-7) converts input objects into a delimited text file. The properties of those objects become the columns/headers and the values become rows that align under the columns. When your input object is a type string, the only property of a string is `Length`. Therefore, the result you see is expected. To achieve the expected behavior, you should use object types that contain the properties you desire or create your own custom objects.

Using custom object, you can do the following, which will create an object with property `Timespan`.

```
[pscustomobject]@{'Timespan' = $ert} |
    Export-Csv C:\Users\User\Documents\output.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation -Encoding ASCII
```

Comment: Thanks again AdminOfThings, for you explanation and help.